# flatten a fiona structure to dictionary for bokeh

Tags: python, pandas, bokeh

I have a fiona data structure 
http://toblerity.org/fiona/manual.html

I try to flatten it so I can plot it in Bokeh.

This is the shorten version and its the zip code boundary shape file from https://www.census.gov

Below is one record e.g. of zip code 43452 from fiona, shorten version

```
{'geometry': {'coordinates': [[(-83.674464, 41.331119),
                               (-83.67444499999999,41.331123999999996),
                               (-83.67215, 41.331634)
]],
              'type': 'Polygon'},
 'id': '1',
 'properties': OrderedDict([('ZCTA5CE10', '43452'),
                            ('GEOID10', '43452'),
                            ('CLASSFP10', 'B5'),
                            ('MTFCC10', 'G6350'),
                            ('FUNCSTAT10', 'S'),
                            ('ALAND10', 121783676),
                            ('AWATER10', 13437379),
                            ('INTPTLAT10', '+41.5157923'),
                            ('INTPTLON10', '-082.9809454')]),
 'type': 'Feature'}
```

https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/gallery/texas.html

I look at the example from Bokeh example
 I need a structure like this

```
    {
'zipcode':[43452] , 'rate':[1]
,'x':[[83.674464,-83.67444499999999,-83.67215]]
,'y':[[41.331119,41.331123999999996,41.331634]]
}
```

as this is one record and let say if I want to do two zip code it will be something like

```
    {
'zipcode':[43452,41111] , 'rate':[1,2]
,'x':[[83.674464,-83.67444499999999,-83.67215],[66.6,-77.7,88.9]]
,'y':[[41.331119,41.331123999999996,41.331634],[66.2,-77.2,88.3]]
}
```

I figure I can do a loop and one record at a time and then append each row to the dictionary structure. It seems ugly and I suppose there is a easier way ?

The code I use to flatten it...ugly..

```
xx=[[*x] for x in zip(*[(1,2),(3,4),(5,6)])]
kk=0
for feat in c:
    kk=kk+1
    #pprint.pprint(feat)   
    if (kk>1):
        break
    #xx=[[*x] for x in zip(*feat['geometry']['coordinates'][0][1])]   
    #pprint.pprint(feat['geometry']['coordinates'][0])
    tt=feat['geometry']['coordinates'][0]
    xx=[[*x] for x in zip(*tt)] 
    x_cor=xx[0]
    y_cor=xx[1]
    print (x_cor)
    print(y_cor)
    #print(xx)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its a lot easier to use Bokeh's `GeoJSONDataSource` when plotting geographic data. The example below shows how to read and convert a shapefile with Fiona and/or GeoPandas, you could use either one. And plot the result with Bokeh.

#### Imports

```
import geopandas as gpd
import fiona
import json

from bokeh.io import show, output_notebook
from bokeh.models import GeoJSONDataSource, LogColorMapper
from bokeh.palettes import Viridis6 as palette
from bokeh.plotting import figure
```

#### Input data

```
shapefile = 'cb_2016_us_county_500k.shp' # from census.gov
```

#### Loading data with Geopandas

```
# read all counties
counties = gpd.read_file(shapefile)

# filter only Texas
texas = counties.query('STATEFP=="48"')

# Export to geojson
geojson = texas.to_json()
```

#### or read with Fiona

```
# open shapefile
with fiona.open(r'D:\Data\US_counties\cb_2016_us_county_500k.shp') as f:

    # filter Texas
    texas = list(filter(lambda x: x['properties']['STATEFP'] == "48",  f.values()))

    # export to geojson
    geojson = json.dumps({'type': 'FeatureCollection', 'features': texas})
```

#### Plot with Bokeh

```
color_column = 'ALAND'

geo_source = GeoJSONDataSource(geojson=geojson)

p = figure(title="Texas")

p.patches('xs', 'ys', fill_alpha=0.7, 
          fill_color={'field': color_column, 'transform': LogColorMapper(palette=palette)}, 
          line_color='black', line_width=0.5, source=geo_source)

show(p)
```

[image]

Comment: Zip Code City County
90001 Los Angeles Los Angeles
90002 Los Angeles Los Angeles
90003 Los Angeles Los Angeles
90004 Los Angeles Los Angeles
90005 Los Angeles Los Angeles

Comment: I can get the list of zip code from the dataframe e.g. df['zipcode'] and how can I construct a lambda function using a column of a dataframe to filter out the fiona structure:     texas = list(filter(lambda x: x['properties']['STATEFP'] == "48",  f.values()))

Comment: I cannot get the fiona filter to work to a group of zipCode from a dataframe but the geospanda.query seems to work

Comment: I try to use merge on geopandas dataframe and a regular dataframe and it does not work for me. I have a df of the zipcode,cityName and then I try to merge it with a shape file. Now I try use the filter function with fiona.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47189226/pass-input-argument-into-python-filter-function

Comment: I end up construct a function which return query string and then using the geopandas .query() something like str='GEOID10 in ["94085","94086","94087","94088","94089"]' It works and still can be optimized ??

Comment: I wasnt sure what dataset you were using and what you were trying to achieve precisely. Its a bit more clear now. Using query seems fine, alternativly something like: `geodf[geodf.GEOID10.isin(zipcodes_to_keep)]`, with `zipcodes_to_keep` being a list of desired zipcodes and `geodf` the DataFrame.